# i have problem how to call data api based on parameters in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

i want to call data api based on the selected parameters, but i'm having a bit of trouble and this has been going on for a few days and it's still not done.

> this is the api you want to fetch data from. and also I marked the
> parameters.

[image]

> and this is when i try to call data api

```
 static Future<Map<String, DataKuliahModel>> getDataKuliah(int smt) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    // String responseJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/1.json');

    Map<String, DataKuliahModel> finalResult = {};
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    final result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    result.forEach((key, value) {
      DataKuliahModel dataKuliah = DataKuliahModel.fromMap(value);
      finalResult.addAll({
        key: dataKuliah,
      });
    });
    return finalResult;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the the url like this

```
Uri.parse(
    '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket?smt=$smt',
  )
```

i hope this will work for you, if not then let me know

Comment: nice, how do i call to card based on parameters 1,2,3 and so on?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DoOEpEZCrhuG3vAEUM0DFK9DUbixbLJA/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @sharon i didn't understood your question can you explain it to me

Comment: so I have a json as drawn, and I want to call the id in the json into the card, but I have difficulties when I want to display it to the user, based on the id in the json.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VyVjWNvzaibxSXOT8o50qbJOLHWzdaJk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

add body to

```
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
      body: {'smt':'7'}
```

or something like that:

```
 var url = Uri.https('www.googleapis.com', '/books/v1/volumes', {'q': '{http}'});
  var response = await http.get(url);
```

Comment: nice, how do i call to card based on parameters 1,2,3 and so on?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DoOEpEZCrhuG3vAEUM0DFK9DUbixbLJA/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1):

***TRY this works***

```
_getData(var smtId){
    final response = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(
                '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket?smt=$smtId',
              ),
              headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
              },

        );
}
```

Comment: nice, how do i call to card based on parameters 1,2,3 and so on?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DoOEpEZCrhuG3vAEUM0DFK9DUbixbLJA/view?usp=share_link